# Extracting percentages from PCA in R

Tags: r, pca

I have PC percentages that I want to extract and use for axis labels

Input:

```
>colnames(df_out)
  [1] "PC1"   "PC2"   "PC3"   "PC4" 
>percentage
            PC1   PC2  PC3  PC4  
    PC1   52.89  0.00 0.00 0.00 
    PC2    0.00 31.69 0.00 0.00 
    PC3    0.00  0.00 6.49 0.00 
    PC4    0.00  0.00 0.00 3.82
```

Desired output:

```
  [1] "PC1 (52.89%)"   "PC2 (31.69%)"   "PC3 (6.49%)"   
  [4] "PC4 (3.82%)"
```

Code

```
percentage <- paste(colnames(df_out), "(", paste(as.character(percentage), "%", ")", sep=""))
```

The above code only gives me the first PC as a percentage, but I want PC2 as well.

Comment: Is that a matrix or data.frame

Answer (score 0):

One option is to extract the `diag`

```
v1 <- diag(as.matrix(percentage))
paste0(names(v1), " (", v1, "%)")
#[1] "PC1 (52.89%)" "PC2 (31.69%)" "PC3 (6.49%)"  "PC4 (3.82%)"
```

#### data

```
percentage <- structure(list(PC1 = c(52.89, 0, 0, 0), PC2 = c(0, 31.69, 0, 
 0), PC3 = c(0, 0, 6.49, 0), PC4 = c(0, 0, 0, 3.82)), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c("PC1", "PC2", "PC3", "PC4"))
```